# How can i insert a GET through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, get, radio-button, submit-button

i have a validation for a radio button, if they checked "yes" or "ya" i want it process or send a GET link like `<a href="?action=profile"></a>`

here's the validation:

```
function persetujuan(){
    var lanjutstep = document.getElementsByName("yesno");
        if (lanjutstep[0].checked == true) {
            //here should be script that send GET variable (?action=profile)
        } else if (lanjutstep[1].checked == true) {
            alert("Maaf Anda tidak bisa melanjutkan, pilih Ya agar bisa melanjutkan.");
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("Silahkan pilih Ya/Tidak");
            return false;
        }
            return true;
}
```

and this for the submit button :

```
<input type="submit" value="Next ==>" onclick="return persetujuan()" />
```

and the radio :

```
<input type="radio" name="yesno" value="setuju" id="lanjut" />Ya
<input type="radio" name="yesno" value="tidak" id="lanjut"/>Tidak
```

thanks a lot for ur help.

Comment: Send a GET link to who?

Comment: Is it in a form ? and you want to change the form's action ?

Comment: Do you prefer to not POST the form?

Comment: @useless intern : i mean i wanna change link addres ex: http://ex.com/form/?action=profile to http://ex.com/form/?action=frm_data

Answer (score 0):

No need for JavaScript at all here.

Just give the radio buttons the name of the field you want to send, and then give the yes button the value "profile".

```
<form>
<label><input type="radio" name="action" value="profile">Ya</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="action" value="">Tidak</label>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: but i need the value "setuju" for i save into database

Comment: But "profile" and "setuju" are just different ways to express the same information (that particular radio button has been checked). Use server side logic if you want to put specific text in the database for that radio button.

Comment: u mean like manipulating? at database still saving profile but at preview we show setuju ?

Answer (score 0):

To change Form element "action" to "frm_data" if "Ya" is selected:

```
if (lanjutstep[0].checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('action').value = 'frm_data';
    return true;
```

And...

```
<form onSubmit="return persetujuan()">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="profile" id="action">
    <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="setuju" id="lanjut" />Ya
    <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="tidak" id="lanjut"/>Tidak
    <input type="submit" value="Next ==>">
</form>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/Ju7h9/

Comment: Open the console, and notice the form is posting to: ?action=frm_data&yesno=setuju